# Circles are not bouncing back

Tags: javascript

A few of my circle objects are not bouncing back, even though I have tried to take care of the edge cases.

I followed everything from here - 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yq2au9EfeRQ

I've tried different ways of passing the Window width and height and changing them in different ways using the radius:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var iW = window.innerWidth;
var iH = window.innerHeight;
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.dx = dx;
  this.dy = dy;
  this.radius = radius;

  this.draw = function() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    c.strokeStyle = "orange";
    c.stroke();
  }

  this.update = function() {
    if (this.x + this.radius > iW || this.x - this.radius < 0) {
      this.dx = ~this.dx;
    }
    if (this.y + this.radius > iH || this.y - this.radius < 0) {
      this.dy = ~this.dy;
    }
    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;

    this.draw();
  }
}

var circleArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var radius = 30;
  var x = Math.random() * (iW - radius * 2) + radius;
  var y = Math.random() * (iH - radius * 2) + radius;
  var dx = Math.random() * 5;
  var dy = Math.random() * 5;
  circleArray.push(new Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius));
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.clearRect(0, 0, iW, iH);
  for (var i = 0; i < circleArray.length; i++) {
    circleArray[i].update();
  }
}
animate();
```

```css
canvas { border : 1px solid black; }
body { margin :0; }
```

```html
<canvas>abcd</canvas>
```

The circles are getting stuck and then are going out of the window after vibrating where they get stuck. They should bounce back but only a few are bouncing back. I am using brackets and also am getting an undefined error I don't know if that error is what is causing this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not negating the `dx` and `dy` values. Instead you are flipping all their binary bits. But then note how `~(-1) === 0`. This roughly explains the problem you see: circles that only move with -1 in either direction, will "bounce" to a move of 0 in that same direction. Consequently they are bouncing again on the next cycle, where they start moving with -1 again, ... and so they wiggle off the canvas.

So just use the minus operator:

```
this.dx = -this.dx;
this.dy = -this.dy;
```